# serverTimestamp() in firestore returns ServerTimestampTransform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, firebase-admin

The following code is suddenly returning ServerTimestampTransform instead of the actual server timestamp

admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

I am using the newest version 8.6.0 of firebase-admin, https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin

Any ideas about this,

-Jani

Comment: If you think a bug was introduced in version 8.6.0 of the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js, you might want to report a bug on [issue tracker on its repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues). Note that there (as here) it's typically very helpful if you provide the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone can quickly run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is what the example outlines in github code

```
/**
   * Returns a sentinel used with set(), create() or update() 
 to include a
   * server-generated timestamp in the written data.
   *
   * @return {FieldValue} The FieldValue sentinel for use in 
 a call to set(),
   * create() or update().
   *
   * @example
   * let documentRef = firestore.doc('col/doc');
   *
   * documentRef.set({
   *   time: Firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    * }).then(() => {
    *   return documentRef.get();
    * }).then(doc => {
    *   console.log(`Server time set to ${doc.get('time')}`);
   * });
   */
  static serverTimestamp(): FieldValue {
    return ServerTimestampTransform.SERVER_TIMESTAMP_SENTINEL;
 }
```

Comment: yes, and what does that mean ? what is SERVER_TIMESTAMP_SENTINEL ? Note that the code has worked before

Answer (score 0):

In firebase functions admin sdk (as of 9.8.0), your alternative is `admin.firestore.Timestamp.now`:

```
const getServerTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now; //Timestamp object getter

let current = getServerTimestamp(); //Creates your Firebase Timestamp object

let jsDate = current.toDate(); //To convert to JS Date object

let unixmili = +new Date(jsDate); //To convert JS Date to unix milliseconds
```

Definition:

```
(method) FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp.now(): FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp
```

> Creates a new timestamp with the current date, with millisecond
> precision.

Since its running on a server, this will be your "Server timestamp".

Remember, UNIX timestamp is timezone independent, so it doesn't matter where firebase server currently is.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't console.log firebase servertimestamps**

If you save the created timestamp to Firestore, it should be visible as a timestamp. But if you just log it in the console it returns "ServerTimestampTransform".

The reason for this (as far as i understood it) is that servertimestamps get filled with an actual timestamp the moment you interact with the server, which makes the timestamp more accurate.